# Android - check file size while recording

Tags: android, file, video, mediarecorder

How can I check video file size while recording using MediaRecorder? And when max file size reached - automatically start recording new video to new file?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the file size with:

```
public long getFileSize(String filepath) {
    File file = new File(filepath);
    if (file.exists())
        return file.length();
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Call this inside an `AsyncTask` or `Timer`, depending on what you want to do with the information, to periodically check the file size and stop the recording and start it again if the max file size is almost reached.